# verilog average, add n-bit numbers together and then divide by nbit numbers

Tags: verilog

I am having trouble putting this code together my main code is a state machine it adds 2 numbers together = sum then loads A to add A to sum(sum=a+sum) after clock is reached it then divides by n bit. I'm lost putting it together. In having Lots of trouble assigning outputs. what is legal and what is not am I able to set the regs equal to each other sometimes I feel like I can do that and some other times I cannot.if I use the module can the input be an output and vice versa I posted my whole code cause I wanted to get it to work. I think my device is correct but I need to create a test bench to tested.

```
module Adder (A1, B1, Cin,Q);
  parameter n = 5;     

  output[n:0]Q;
  reg [n:0]Q;

  input [n:0] A1;
    wire[n:0] A1;
  input [n:0] B1;
    wire [n:0] B1;  
input Cin;

  always @(A1 or B1 or Cin)
begin
    Q = A1 +B1 + Cin;
end
endmodule




module ave(Clk,X,LA,DataA,Sum,Q);
parameter n=5;
input A,B,EB,Temp,DataA,DataB,Sum,Q;
input X;
reg A,B,Temp,Sum;
reg y,Y
wire 
reg S1=3'b000;S2=3'b001;S3=3'b010;S4=3'b011;S5=3'b100;
always (Clk)
begin
case(y)

S1:
     y=S2;
S2:

     y=S3;
S3:
if (counter>0) y=S2;
    else y=S4;
S4: 
    y=S4;

S5:
    Done;

endcase
end


always (Clk)
begin
case

S1:
    Counter=n; Temp=n; Sum=0;
S2:

    A=X;
S3:
if (counter>0) B<=A+B; 
    else B<=B;
S4: 
    DataA=Temp;
    DataB=Sum;



S5:
    Done=1;


end

Adder add(A,Sum,Cin,Sum);
divider divid(Clk,1,1,1,1,DataA,DataB,1,1,Q,0);




endmodule
```

this is my divider plus the other modules:

```
module shiftlne(R,C,L,w,Clk,Q);
parameter n=8;
input [n-1:0]R;
input L,w,Clk,C;
output [n-1:0]Q;
reg [n-1:0]Q;
integer k;
always @(posedge Clk)
begin

    if(L)begin
        if(C)begin
    Q<=R;end
    else
    begin
    for (k=0;k<(n-1);k=(k+1))
        Q[k+1]=Q[k];
        Q[0]<=w;
    end

        end
end
endmodule

module downcounter (R,E,L,Clk,Q);
parameter n=8;
input[n-1:0]R;
input Clk,L,E;
output [n-1:0]Q;
reg[n-1:0]Q;

always @(posedge Clk)
begin   if(L)
        Q<=R;
    else if(E)
        Q<=(Q-1);
end
endmodule



module muxdff(  D0, D1, Sel, Clk,Q);
input Clk,D0,D1,Sel;
wire D;
output Q;
reg Q;
assign D=Sel?D1:D0;
always @ (posedge Clk)
begin
        Q=D;

end
endmodule


module regne (R,Clk,Resetn,E,Q);
parameter n=8;

input [n-1:0]R;
input Clk,Resetn,E;
output [n-1:0]Q;
reg [n-1:0] Q;

always @(posedge Clk or negedge Resetn)
begin
if (Resetn==0)
    Q<=0;
else if (E)
 Q<=R;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: 'I'm lost' is not a question, please ask something specific, what's giving you problems.

Answer (score 2):

Are you stuck using Verilog-95 if not you can clean up the code style, if nothing else it helps spot the bugs easier.

NB: Uses spaces to indent your code, not tabs as they mess up the formatting when posting Q's and can look different to people review your code depending on how there editor is setup.

```
module Adder #(
  parameter n = 5
)(
  input      [n:0] A1, //Inputs do not have to be declared as wires
  input      [n:0] B1,  
  input            Cin,
  output reg [n:0] Q;
);

  //Auto sensitivity list with @* lowers chance of bugs
  always @* begin
    Q = A1 + B1 + Cin;
  end

endmodule
```

Most languages, and I apply this to my verilog keep constants like `parameter`s and `localparam` in UPPERCASE, everything else is lowercase.

Your shiftlne code be made more readable: readable code to me implies easier to spot the bugs and understand the design intention.

```
always @(posedge Clk) begin
  if( L ) begin
    if( C ) begin
      Q <= R;
    end
    else begin
      for (k=0;k<(n-1);k=(k+1))
        Q[k+1] =  Q[k];  //For loop only applies to this line
                         //  should it not be Q[k+1] <= Q[k];
        Q[0]   <= w;
    end
  end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Where I'm getting stuck is outputting.in a module can I use an input as an output and vice a versa. Also can I set regs equal to each other if so where can I do that. I end up getting illegal left hand assignment.

Comment: @user2941970 input and output are declarations of how the signal is driven, it does not make sense to drive them the wrong way, and it will. It work in the simulator. You can assign a wire to the value of a reg. wire a_wire = a_reg;

Comment: that makes sense.do I need to use the assign command. if also if I plan to use that wire twice do I need two wires can I use the same wire. thank you for the quick response

Comment: @user2941970 You need think of a wire as literally a wire connecting hardware blocks, it is not a variable holding temporary values. You likely need 2 this case.